# PHP Scripts not showing any error on Localhost?

Tags: php, localhost

I am wondering why my http://localhost/ server is not displaying any error?
I am throwing errors like "require(abc.php);" which doesn't exists,

Tried throwing every error, but either screen goes blank or the actual output comes, but no error is reported.

I also wrote **error_reporting(E_ALL);** on top of the file, but still, can't figure out.

Comment: have you checked about ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Thanks, but still no error is shown on the page. I am crying. :(

Comment: oops, sorry, I forgot to restart apache. Now its working. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: this question has already asked open the link here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look to your php.ini if the "display_errors" is set to "1" or you can set the variable over php with:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: No problem. Sometimes its set to 0 in production environment.

Answer (score 2):

try to set

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

as well.